# Does a proper nash embedding exist?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have thoroughly examined all available references. While these sources mention that a complete manifold can be isometrically embedded in a Euclidean space, they do not explicitly address the existence of a properly isometric embedding. I am eager to know if anyone has information on whether such an embedding exists, as this is of utmost importance to me